# Creating an index array of all commas in array

Tags: c

I am trying to create an index array that will store the location of every ',' that is read in from a file.  I have written the code and it seems to work but for some reason stops after exactly 1 ',' past the first line in the file.

What in the world is causing it to stop I cant figure it out.  It just gives zeros after the first couple indexes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getCommaIndex(int n,char table[],int index[]){
int i;
int p = 0;
for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
    if(table[i] == ','){
        index[p] = i;
        p++;
    }
}    
}

int main()
{
char table[100000];
int index[5000];
int i;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/Open Frameworks/apps/myApps/bin/data/tableshort.csv","r");

while( !feof(fp)){
    fgets(table,"%s",fp);
    printf("%s",table);
    getCommaIndex(5000,table,index);
}

for(i = 0 ; i < 11 ; i++){
    printf("%d ",index[i]);
}
```

Output will look something like:

7 11 20 35 40 59 62 67 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to use `fgets` like that.

Comment: I've spent too long on the internet. I misread fgets. Rethink how you are doing this. I think you are looking at the problem the wrong way. If you just want the numbered output from your csv file, you can use the comma as your delimiter. If you need help parsing a string with a delimiter there are numerous answers on SO.

Comment: Are you sure you get the positions of the first line? As I see it, your program should print the positions in the very last line of the file.

Comment: Yes it is the first line.  What about the code makes you think the last line would be printed?

Answer (score 0):

I just changed:

```
fgets(table,"%s",fp);
```

to:

```
fgets(table,5000,fp);
```

and everything worked.

See: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm

Also, your code in your question gave me this message in my compiler: `warning: passing argument 2 of 'fgets' makes integer from pointer without a cast`. Treat warnings as errors as much as you can.

Comment: I just tried this and it makes no difference on my end...  How did you test that everything works without the file to read from?

Comment: I created my own file, saved it, and ran the program against it. This is the contents of my file: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,A,B,C`. Also, check to make sure your disk is working correctly.

Comment: That works fine for me as well.  Try putting a return in there somewhere so its more like  <br/>1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
        a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h

Comment: Well I cant figure out how to show a next line in a comment...  But I think you get what I'm saying.  so if you open the CSV in notepad it will show some text on the first line then finish on the second

Comment: What happens if you create the file with the plainest editor such as the MS-DOS editor? Yes I know its old-school but some new editors like to save data in their own encoded format

Comment: If it was a small amount of data that would be an option.  However the excel file has over 10000 lines to it.  I changed it from fgets to fgetc and that made it work...

Comment: But fgetc goes after 1 byte at a time where fgets goes after a specified number of bytes. If you're reading a super large file (long lines) then I think fgetc will be slower

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading the entire file at once, you could try reading a single line at a time. Also, in your getCommaIndex function table[] is 100000 but you only iterate over the first 5000 indices. It is not clear to me but it seems like you value for n should be 100000 so you loop over the entire table array.

Comment: You are correct.  I just was not worried about it as I am having trouble over the first 10  I don't need to go all the way through the entire table yet.